# Can we use JPA outsite EJB container?

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, jboss7.x

My application is running on Jboss 4.0.5 GA and need to be upgraded to run on jboss 7.1.1 final. Everything in JSF pages, business logic are solved. But the critical thing we're facing: In old application in jboss4 we do not use JPA, we use hibernate session directly. And manage hibernate session by threadlocal. We applied 3 tiers application: [UI backend bean] call [EJB to execute business] call [DAO objects to get and update database by hibernate session]. 
This design is broken, NOW! Because we cannnot find the way to manage entity manager in threadlocal like hibernate session. May be I'm bad developer.
Please help me, can we use jpa outsite EJB. I would like a static class with name DAOUtil to manage and get entity manager, also perform save or update data. Anyone tell me the way to do this. How about datasource(xa-datasource), how about persistent.xml?
This is class to access to databse:

```
package com.esilicon.dao.hibernate;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;

import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.SQLQuery;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Example;
import org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionImplementor;

public class HibernateDAOSession extends DAOSession {


    /**
     * @associates Class
     */
    private static HashMap implementations = new HashMap();
    private Session hibernateSession;
    // private Transaction tx;
    private boolean JTAEnvironment;
    private EntityManager em;

    public HibernateDAOSession(Session s, boolean jta) {
        this.hibernateSession = s;
        this.JTAEnvironment = false;
    }

    public HibernateDAOSession(Session s, boolean jta, EntityManager em) {
        this.hibernateSession = s;
        this.JTAEnvironment = false;
        this.em = em;
    }

    public BaseDAO getDAO(Class clazz) {
        try {
            Class impl = getImplementationClass(clazz);
            HibernateDAO dao = (HibernateDAO) impl.newInstance();
            // dao.setCurrentSession(this.getHibernateSession());
            // session will be provided by DAOUtil from a threadlocal variable.
            return dao;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private Class getImplementationClass(Class clazz) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        Class impl = (Class) implementations.get(clazz);
        if (impl == null) {
            String name = clazz.getName();
            String packageName = clazz.getPackage().getName();
            String className = name.substring(packageName.length() + 1);
            StringBuffer implClassName = new StringBuffer(packageName).append(".hibernate.").append(className).append("DAO");
            impl = Class.forName(implClassName.toString());
            implementations.put(clazz, impl);
        }
        return impl;
    }

    public void close() {
        if (this.JTAEnvironment)
            return;
        try {
            Session s = this.getHibernateSession();
            if (s != null && s.isOpen() && this.getEm() != null) {
                s.close();
                this.setHibernateSession(null);
                /*
                 * this.getEm().clear(); this.getEm().close();
                 */
                this.setEm(null);
            }

            /*if (s != null && s.isOpen()) {

            }*/

        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new HibernateDAOException(e);
        }

    }

    public void beginTransaction() {
        try {
            /*if (getHibernateSession().getTransaction() == null) {
                this.getHibernateSession().beginTransaction();
            } else if (!getHibernateSession().getTransaction().isActive() || getHibernateSession().getTransaction().wasCommitted()) {
                getHibernateSession().getTransaction().begin();
            }*/
            //return getHibernateSession().getTransaction();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new HibernateDAOException(e);
        }
    }

    public void commit() {
        //this.getHibernateSession().flush();
        /*if (this.JTAEnvironment)
            return;
        try {
            if (getHibernateSession().getTransaction() != null && getHibernateSession().getTransaction().isActive()) {
                getHibernateSession().getTransaction().commit();
            }
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            rollback();
            throw new HibernateDAOException(e);
        }*/
    }

    public void rollback() {
        // TODO: should we allow rolback on session in JTAEnvironment ?
        /*try {
            if (getHibernateSession().getTransaction() != null && getHibernateSession().getTransaction().isActive()) {
                getHibernateSession().getTransaction().rollback();
            }
        } finally {
            // close();
            DAOUtil.closeEntityManager();
        }*/
    }

    public Transaction getCurrentTransaction() {
        return getHibernateSession().getTransaction();
    }

    private Query prepareQuery(Query q, int start, int count, Map params) {
        String[] namedParams = q.getNamedParameters();
        if (namedParams.length > 0 && params != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < namedParams.length; i++) {
                if (params.get(namedParams[i]) instanceof java.util.List) {
                    q.setParameterList(namedParams[i], (List) params.get(namedParams[i]));
                } else {
                    q.setParameter(namedParams[i], params.get(namedParams[i]));
                }
            }
        }
        if (start >= 0)
            q.setFirstResult(start);
        if (count >= 0)
            q.setMaxResults(count);
        return q;
    }

    public Session getHibernateSession() {
        return hibernateSession;
    }

    public void setHibernateSession(Session hibernateSession) {
        this.hibernateSession = hibernateSession;
    }

    public Object update(Object o) {
        try {
            this.getHibernateSession().update(o);
            return o;
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new HibernateDAOException(e);
        }

    }

    public boolean isJTAEnvironment() {
        return JTAEnvironment;
    }

    public Object save(Object o) {
        try {
            this.getHibernateSession().save(o);
            return o;
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new HibernateDAOException(e);
        }
    }

    public Object saveOrUpdate(Object o) {
        try {
            this.getHibernateSession().saveOrUpdate(o);
            return o;
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new HibernateDAOException(e);
        }

    }

    public void flush() {
        try {
            this.getHibernateSession().flush();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new HibernateDAOException(e);
        }
    }

    public Object refresh(Object o) {
        try {
            this.getHibernateSession().refresh(o);
            return o;
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new HibernateDAOException(e);
        }
    }

    public void evict(Object o) {
        try {
            this.getHibernateSession().evict(o);
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new HibernateDAOException(e);
        }
    }

    public Object query(String query, Map map, boolean uniqueResult) {
        try {
            Query q = this.getHibernateSession().createQuery(query);
            prepareParameters(q, map);
            if (uniqueResult) {
                return q.uniqueResult();
            } else {
                return q.list();
            }
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new HibernateDAOException(e);
        }
    }

    private void prepareParameters(Query q, Map map) {
        if (map == null)
            return;
        String[] params = q.getNamedParameters();
        for (int i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
            if (map.get(params[i]) instanceof java.util.List) {
                q.setParameterList(params[i], (List) map.get(params[i]));
            } else {
                q.setParameter(params[i], map.get(params[i]));
            }
        }
    }

    public Connection getConnection() {
        SessionImplementor si = (SessionImplementor) getHibernateSession();
        //this.connection = si.connection();
        return si.connection();
    }

    public void delete(Object o) {
        try {
            this.getHibernateSession().delete(o);
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new HibernateDAOException(e);
        }

    }

    public Object findUniqueEntityByID(Class entityClass, Serializable id) {
        try {
            return this.getHibernateSession().get(entityClass, id);
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new HibernateDAOException(e);
        }
    }

    public int executeUpdate(String query, Map params) {
        try {
            Query q = this.getHibernateSession().createQuery(query);
            prepareParameters(q, params);
            return q.executeUpdate();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new HibernateDAOException(e);
        }
    }

    public Object nativeQuery(String query, Map map, boolean uniqueResult) {
        try {
            Query q = this.getHibernateSession().createSQLQuery(query);
            prepareParameters(q, map);
            if (uniqueResult) {
                return q.uniqueResult();
            } else {
                return q.list();
            }
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new HibernateDAOException(e);
        }
    }

    public int executeNativeUpdate(String query, Map params) {
        try {
            Query q = this.getHibernateSession().createSQLQuery(query);
            prepareParameters(q, params);
            return q.executeUpdate();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new HibernateDAOException(e);
        }
    }

    public EntityManager getEm() {
        return em;
    }

    public void setEm(EntityManager em) {
        this.em = em;
    }

    @Override
    public Query createQuery(String hqlQuery) {
        return getHibernateSession().createQuery(hqlQuery);
    }

    @Override
    public SQLQuery createSQLQuery(String nativeQuery) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return getHibernateSession().createSQLQuery(nativeQuery);
    }

    @Override
    public void disconnect() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        getHibernateSession().disconnect();
    }

    @Override
    public Object get(Class<?> clazz, Serializable id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return getHibernateSession().get(clazz, id);
    }

    @Override
    public Object load(Class<?> clazz, Serializable id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return getHibernateSession().load(clazz, id);
    }

    @Override
    public Object merge(Object o) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return getHibernateSession().merge(o);
    }

    @Override
    public Query getNamedQuery(String nameQuery) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return getHibernateSession().getNamedQuery(nameQuery);
    }
}
```

Class to manage HibernateSessionDAO

```
package com.esilicon.dao;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.proxy.HibernateProxy;

import com.esilicon.dao.hibernate.HibernateDAOSession;
import com.esilicon.util.logging.Logger;

public class DAOUtil {
    public static final String PERSISTENT_UNIT = "vms4_jboss7";

    static ThreadLocal<DAOSession> threadLocalDAOEntityManager = new ThreadLocal<DAOSession>();
    static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(DAOUtil.class.getName());

    public static DAOSession openEntityManager(DAOEntityManagerFactory factory) {
        DAOSession entityManager = (DAOSession) threadLocalDAOEntityManager.get();
        if (entityManager != null && entityManager.isOpen()) {
            return entityManager;
        }
        try {
            entityManager = factory.getEntityManager();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // e.printStackTrace();
            entityManager = factory.openEntityManager();
        }
        threadLocalDAOEntityManager.set(entityManager);
        return entityManager;
    }

    public static DAOSession openSession(DAOSessionFactory factory) {

        DAOSession daoSession = (DAOSession) threadLocalDAOEntityManager.get();
        if (daoSession != null && daoSession.isOpen()) {
            return daoSession;
        }
        try {
            threadLocalDAOEntityManager.remove();
            daoSession = factory.getSession();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            daoSession = factory.openSession();
        }
        threadLocalDAOEntityManager.set(daoSession);
        return daoSession;
    }

    public static DAOSession openSession(DAOEntityManagerFactory factory) {

        return openEntityManager(factory);
    }

    public static DAOSession getEntityManager() {
        DAOSession entityManager = (DAOSession) threadLocalDAOEntityManager.get();
        if (entityManager == null || !entityManager.isOpen()) {
            entityManager = DAOUtil.openEntityManager(DAOEntityManagerFactory.getInstance(null));
        }
        return entityManager;
    }

    public static DAOSession getSession() {
        return getEntityManager();
    }

    public static void closeEntityManager() {
        DAOSession entityManager = (DAOSession) threadLocalDAOEntityManager.get();
        if (entityManager != null) {
            entityManager.close();
            logger.debug("EntityManager Closed for Thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            threadLocalDAOEntityManager.remove();
        }
    }

    public static void closeSession() {
        closeEntityManager();
    }

    public static void beginTransaction() {
        DAOSession entityManager = (DAOSession) threadLocalDAOEntityManager.get();
        logger.debug("--- BeginTransaction --- Thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        if (entityManager == null) {
            entityManager = openEntityManager(DAOEntityManagerFactory.getInstance(null));
        }
        entityManager.beginTransaction();
    }

    public static void commitTransaction() {
        DAOSession entityManager = (DAOSession) threadLocalDAOEntityManager.get();
        logger.debug("--- CommitTransaction --- Thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        entityManager.commit();
    }

    public static void rollbackTransaction() {
        DAOSession entityManager = (DAOSession) threadLocalDAOEntityManager.get();
        if (entityManager != null && entityManager.isOpen()) {
            entityManager.rollback();
        }
    }

    public static BaseDAO getDAO(Class clazz) {
        return getEntityManager().getDAO(clazz);
    }

    public static Object narrow(Object proxy) {

        try {
            return ((HibernateProxy) proxy).getHibernateLazyInitializer().getImplementation();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return proxy; // not a proxy
        }

    }

    public static void closeConnection(Connection con) {
        try {
            if (con != null && !con.isClosed()) {
                con.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static Connection getNonXAConnection() {
        try {
            InitialContext context = new InitialContext();
            DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) context.lookup(JNDILookup.PURE_CONNECTION_JNDI);
            return dataSource.getConnection();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            logger.fatal(e.getMessage(), e.getCause());
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you managing your transactions? Using UserTransaction or EntityManager's transactions? What was the problem that you solved using a thread local? Did you use it to initialize transaction + EntityManager in a servlet filter?

Comment: you can see, I have the object of EntityManager but I cannot use it because error related to managed transaction. I must workaround by unwrap hibernate session. With my implementation, how can use EntityManager instead of HibernateSession?

Comment: It seems like you are managing transactions using entitymanager. Try disabling container managed transactions from persistence.xml. See http://tomee.apache.org/jpa-concepts.html for information how to configure persistence unit to use RESOURCE_LOCAL transactions

Answer (score 0):

Use dependency injection to inject the entity manager into your dao classes:

For example:

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

Comment: DAO class is not a EJB, just a pure java class. However if I can inject entity manager, I think I cannot perform save/update by manually.

Comment: The DAO class needs to be managed anyway. How are you creating a new instance? Just mark the class to be: @Singleton(name = "myDaoObject"). The enity manager has methods like persist, remove, find, etc... or createQuery if you want to write a custom sql statement.

Comment: Im core of DAOs, I've a object named is HibernateSessionDAO, its managed by theadlocal. I case of using, I get this object from threadlocal. This object has property as EntityManager, but I cannot persist without error:Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Connection is not associated with a managed connection.org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk6.WrappedConnectionJDK6@22b4e311
      at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection.lock(WrappedConnection.java:154)
      at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection.prepareStatement(WrappedConnection.java:394)

Comment: Do NOT make your dao class a singleton, if you are injecting entity manager in it! EntityManager is not thread safe